# Show each point of loop iteration with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, loops, animation, opengl, while-loop

I am currently working on graphing the lorenz attractor in 3D space and am trying to animate the graphing of it on the screen. I have written the following while loop in my display function thinking that it will do as i expect.

```
int i;
float x = 0, y = 1, z = 0;
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
   
while (i < initialIterations) {
    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    // compute a new point using the strange attractor equations
    float dx = sigma*(y-x);
    float dy = x*(r-z) - y;
    float dz = x*y - b*z;
    
    // save the new point
    x = x + dx*dt;
    y = y + dy*dt;
    z = z + dz*dt;        
    
    glVertex3f(x/50,y/50,z/50);
    i++;
}

glEnd();
```

however it just graphs the whole attractor and doesnt show each iteration.

Comment: What is internalIterations? Where do you set it?

Comment: initialiterations is just a set number of 50000

Answer (score 4):

If your context is **double-buffered**, then it won't be possible to see this animate because it draws everything offscreen and then flips the picture to the screen once you call swapbuffers.

If you want to work around this, instead of drawing the entire attractor, setup a loop counter such that on frame 0, you only draw point 0, on frame 1 you draw points 0 to 1, on frame 2 you draw points 0 to 2, etc.

If your context is **single-buffered**, you can see it animate as you draw, though it's likely so fast that you'd never be able to see it animate. It probably finishes drawing that loop in about a millisecond. You'll need to put some kind of wait or sleep in between each loop if you want the animation to be visible to the human eye.

Comment: You can always draw to the front buffer by seleting it as render operation target using glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>

struct Vertex
{
    Vertex( float x, float y, float z ) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
std::vector< Vertex > verts;

void fillVerts()
{
    // calculate vertices
    // http://paulbourke.net/fractals/lorenz/
    int N = 10000;
    int i = 0;
    double x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1;
    double h = 0.01;
    double a = 10.0;
    double b = 28.0;
    double c = 8.0 / 3.0;

    x0 = 0.1;
    y0 = 0;
    z0 = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        x1 = x0 + h * a * (y0 - x0);
        y1 = y0 + h * (x0 * (b - z0) - y0);
        z1 = z0 + h * (x0 * y0 - c * z0);
        x0 = x1;
        y0 = y1;
        z0 = z1;

        if( i > 100 )
        {
            verts.push_back( Vertex( x0, y0, z0 ) );
        }
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -10 );

    // spin
    static float angle = 0;
    angle += 0.1;
    glRotatef( angle, 1, 1, 1 );

    // resize
    float s = 1 / 10.0f;
    glScalef(s,s,s);

    // animate index
    static size_t curIdx = 0;
    curIdx += 2;
    if( curIdx >= verts.size() )
        curIdx = 0;

    // draw curve
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &verts[0] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, curIdx );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 60, (double)w / (double)h, 1.0, 10000.0 );
}

void timer(int extra)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(16, timer, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutCreateWindow("Attractor");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);

    fillVerts();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

It uses `glutTimerFunc()` to poke the display function every 16 milliseconds or so, at which point it draws the next two Lorenz vertices.